# Is it possible to define a cross-platform working directory for R?

Tags: r, setwd

I am teaching R tutorials in person w/ a large number of undergraduate R novices.  I am also trying to format my notes on RPubs so that they can easily be used by other people.  Nothing derails things faster than people mis-specifying working directories or saving spreadsheet files to someplace different than their working directory.

Is it possible to define a working directory that is universal across platforms?  For example, a line of code or a function like

```
setwd( someplace that is likely to exist on every computer)
```

This could involve a function that finds some place the usually exists on all computers, such as the desktop, downloads folder, or R directory.

Comment: Setting the directory to be a relative path instead of absolute path is a more generally accepted method for making your code portable. something like `setwd("./working")` possibly.

Comment: `path.expand("~")` will give you the user's home directory on Windows as well as Unix-like platforms.

Answer (score 5):

In general your best bet is to go for the user's home area,

```
setwd("~")
path.expand("~")
```

Since you are teaching novices, a common problem is that students notice the R package directory `~/R/` and assume that they should put their scripts this directory; thereby creating odd bugs. To avoid this, I would go for

```
dir.create("~/RCourse", FALSE)
setwd("~/RCourse")
```

If you use RStudio, you could get them to create an RStudio project.

In the past, I have come across situations where this doesn't work. For example, some people have their home area as a network drive, but can't connect to the internet or get through a firewall.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about

> someplace that is likely to exist on every computer

and yes, R works hard to ensure this returns a valid directory:  `tempdir()`.

The main danger, though, may be that this directory will vanish after the session (unless you override the default behaviour of removing the per-session temporary directory at end).  Until then, it works.

Still, this can be useful. I [sometimes use that](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rvw/blob/master/demo/vw_example_4.R#L27-L30) to write temporary files I don't want to clutter in the current directory, or `~`.

Otherwise @csgillespie gave you a good answer pertaining to `$HOME` aka `~`.